# Read all documents from collection from firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I try to read all documents from collection as a model List from firestore like the java code.

Java code is

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Product").addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
            if (!value.isEmpty()){
                List<Product> productList = value.toObjects(Product.class);
            }
        });
```

I try in flutter

```
QuerySnapshot data;
    List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot = new List<DocumentSnapshot>();
    List<Product> productList = [];

    data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Product')
        .get();

    
      snapshot.addAll(data.docs);
      productList = snap.map((e) => Product.fromFirestore(e)).toList();
```

but always the list is empty, but the **snapshot** length is always same as my database.

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA1RL.png)
[Model class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW4Yi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void getProducts () async {
List<Product> productList = [];
var productsFromFirebase = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Product").get();

 if (productsFromFirebase.docs.isNotEmpty) {

   for (var doc in productsFromFirebase.docs) {
   productList.add(Product.fromFirestore(doc)); //without '.data()' because you have it in your model.
   } 
 }
 print(productList.length); //prints the length of your products list.
}
```